# Parse timeZone specific Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have a user base of 2,000+. I've done a lot to mitigate API requests with a scaleable app. However, I recently introduced a new feature to my app, subscribing to particular alerts to receive a push notification when that object gets updated. This is great for users, bad for my project since it's Parse incorporation is extensive. I thought a good way to limit the requests per minute would be to send push notifications to a user dependent on their timeZone. So users in Asia won't receive it at the same time a user in Florida will. I would like it to send anywhere from 8am to 11am, according to the users relative time zone.

The question is **without cloud code/REST API** what's a sufficient way to send/schedule pushes in those regards? We can already set the time zone parameter when constructing a push payload, but how do we enumerate through all the users' time zones subscribed to that alert, to ensure they receive the push as expected? Preferably, autonomously.

Answer (score 0):

In "Create custom audience" you can add the timezone condition

[image]